# How can I remove the key from fluent-bit output?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am using the following input in fluent-bit configuration of Kubernetes ConfigMap (YAML):

```
    [INPUT]
        Name          mem
        Tag           memory_usage
        Interval_Sec  60
        Interval_NSec 0
```

which provides output like:

```
{
    "_aws": {
        "Timestamp": 1617303986000,
        "CloudWatchMetrics": [
            {
                "Namespace": "fluent-bit-metrics",
                "Dimensions": [],
                "Metrics": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Mem.total",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Mem.used",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Mem.free",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Swap.total",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Swap.used",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Swap.free",
                        "Unit": "Bytes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "Mem.total": 32676948,
    "Mem.used": 25955580,
    "Mem.free": 6721368,
    "Swap.total": 0,
    "Swap.used": 0,
    "Swap.free": 0
}
```

I am trying to remove _aws key and all its values by using this filter, but no success:

```
    [FILTER]
        Name record_modifier
        Match *
        Remove_key _aws
```

**Can you suggest something with this issue?**

Comment: What are you observing when you run this configuration?

Comment: I am still observing what I have put above. No changes

Comment: Can you please share the logs as well?

Comment: 2021-04-09T13:52:23.936+01:00
null

2021-04-09T13:53:24.137+01:00
null

Comment: As you can see they come empty. I think there is a bug with CloudFront output. As I tested with stdout output, it worked ok.

Comment: What output do you see with stdout output plugin?